# Is there a way to attach documents to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to manage a set of documents with Google Sheets.

I tried service like Evernote but I prefer displaying those document in a table form.

Comment: I was asking the same question, researched and posted [here](http://howto.philippkeller.com/2014/01/20/How-to-attach-a-file-to-google-spreadsheet/) a solution

Answer (score 2):

If the documents are Google docs, you can attach the internet address of the Google doc in the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by attach? I mean, what behavior do you expect?

Anyway, the only way I think is to upload this document, if it's not already an online document, you want to attach to somewhere online accessible, e.g. your Google Docs, and place the document link on a cell.